# XML - how to match children to its parent

Tags: xml, xslt

Below are the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="85%" align="left">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="reporttable" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tableheader" align="center">Claim No</td>
                                    <td class="tableheader" align="center">Name</td>
                                    <td class="tableheader" align="center">Gross Total Amount</td>
                                    <td class="tableheader" align="center">Expense Type</td>
                                    <td class="tableheader" align="center">CNumber</td>
                                    <td class="tableheader" align="center">Code</td>
                                </tr>
                                <xsl:for-each select="//claims">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Number"/></td>
                                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Fullname"/></td>
                                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@GrossTotalAmount"/></td>                                     
                                    <xsl:for-each select="//row">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                                        <td class="tablecontent1"><xsl:value-of select="@ExpenseType"/></td>
                                        <td class="tablecontent1"><xsl:value-of select="@CNumber"/></td>
                                        <td class="tablecontent1"><xsl:value-of select="@Code"/></td>
                                        <td class="tablecontent1"><xsl:value-of select="@Party"/></td>
                                        <td class="tablecontent1"><xsl:value-of select="@T8Code"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </tr>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and input xml

```
<claims Number="xQAJUN1048" Fullname="almond pdr" GrossTotalAmount="6747.00">
    <row element="item" CNumber="xQAJUN1048" ExpenseType="AC FIXED ASSET" Code="-" />
    <row element="item" CNumber="xQAJUN1048" ExpenseType="ADM CENTRE &amp; VAT/TAXES" Code="FEP" />
</claims>
<claims Number="M11JUN1053" Fullname="almond pdr" GrossTotalAmount="450.00">
    <row element="item" CNumber="M11JUN1053" ExpenseType="ANT FIXED ASSET" Code="ASTON" />
</claims>
<claims Number="xQAJUN1060" Fullname="almond pdr" GrossTotalAmount="240.00">
    <row element="item" CNumber="xQAJUN1060" ExpenseType="CDF FIXED ASSET" Code="ASTON" />
</claims>
```

I need to generate an output similar to the one in the attached screen. currently all the child records are mapped for all the master records.

Can any one guide me on this :)

Thanks

:( sorry unable to post images due to site restriction

Comment: you should edit your question it is not clear. Thanks

Comment: the children should displayed under its corresponding parent based on the Number in root/claims/Number and CNumber in root/claims/row/CNumber. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have done the 99% of the work. If I understand correctly, you want the records be mapped for the specific master record according to the `root/claims/Number` and `root/claims/row/CNumber` correspondences. Given the input sample in your question, seems that you only need to change a row in your XSLT, because data is already correctly grouped.

That is, change this:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//row">
```

which selects all rows in the input document, to this:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="row">
```

which selects the rows in the current context. If you change this row, child records will appear under the corresponding master record.

Comment: @mzjn I'm a new registrant to this site and the site restricts to upload images until the 10th post.

Comment: Thanks Guru.This is what exactly i'm looking for.  Thanks for correcting/teaching me.

Comment: Sorry i've overlooked the feature.  Now i've 'Accept'ed it:)